# "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error when installed Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) on ubuntu?

Tags: eclipse, segmentation-fault

I had eclipse kepler before but it was closed unexpectedly and refused to start, when i click on it the logo shows and suddenly disappears without showing any error, i searched and found some solutions like to reinstall eclipse and Java or deleting the Workspace, I installed the Java again, deinstalled eclipse kepler and deleted the workspace, and after that I downloaded eclipse neon but still have same issue when i click on eclipse i get the logo and the window that asks for the path to the workspace but when i click on "browse" or "ok" on this window the it disappears without any error message, i tried to run eclipse from terminal to get any error, when i run ./eclipse i get the logo and the window asks for workspace path, and when i click on it i get the following error in terminal

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the  
 state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is
```

initialized.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

i tried also to install kepler and mars and even to run the eclipse installer but all the three fail with the same exact error above

OS:
Linux Jack 4.4.0-81-generic #104-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 14 08:15:00 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

```
Java version installed: 
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

i have installed from: eclipse-jee-neon-3-linux-gtk.tar.gz

Hint: i have not set the vm option in "eclipse.ini"

I have JAVA_HOME set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

"eclipse.ini" contains the following:

-startup
`plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
       -vmargs
      -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
       -XX:+UseG1GC
       -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
      -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
     -Xms256m
    -Xmx1024m`

I have found the following bug report but it does not contain any suggestion, how to fix this?
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=473789

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: If you have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or 16.04 LTS the problem may be caused by new kernel updates. See [Bug #1699772: linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic, linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic Regression: many user-space apps crashing](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1699772). The solution is to reboot with previous kernel (linux-image-3.13.0-119-generic in Trusty / linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic in Xenial).

Comment: Thank you N0rbert and miken32 for your answers, it seems there is a fix in the way for the Ubuntu Kernel Regression, https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2017-June/017507.html , until the fix is available rebooting into the previous kernel seems to be the only solution for now as N0rbert said